# Sangria GraphQL: How to mix deferred fields, deriveObjectType, and case classes

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I'm curious if it's possible to define a case class's field as deferred while still using the `deriveObjectType` macro to define everything else.

Here's an example. Dashboards contain a sequence of tabs:

```
case class Tab(id: Long, dashboardId: Long, name: String, order: Long)

case class Dashboard(id: Long, name: String, tabs: Seq[Tab])
```

I'm deferring resolution of the `Dashboard.tabs` field using a `Fetcher`, AND I'd like to continue using the `deriveObjectType` macro (if possible). So here's how I've defined my `ObjectType`s:

```
val TabType = deriveObjectType[Unit, Dashboard]()

val DashboardType = deriveObjectType[Unit, Dashboard](
  AddFields(
    fields =
      Field(
        name = "tabs",
        fieldType = ListType(TabType),
        resolve = ctx => {
          TabsFetcher.fetcher.defer(ctx.value.id)
        }
      )
  )
)
```

But, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
sangria.schema.NonUniqueFieldsError: All fields within 'Dashboard' type should have unique names! Non-unique fields: 'tabs'.
```

If I remove the `tabs` field from the `Dashboard` case class the error goes away, but I lose some of the benefit of using a case class (especially in unit tests). And if I avoid the use of the `deriveObjectType` macro (and define the `Dashboard`'s `ObjectType` manually), then I lose the benefits of the macro (less boilerplate).

So, I'm curious if there's a better way, or another way, around this issue short of defining the `DashboardType` without the use of the macro or removing the `tags` field from the `Dashboard` case class.

(I was hoping that there might be some sort of `@GraphQLDeferred` annotation that I could apply to the `Dashboard.tabs` field or something similar???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. You need use `ReplaceField` instead of `AddFields`. Alternatively you can `ExcludeFields("tabs")` and continue using `AddFields`.